# create graphics of entire screen

Tags: c#, graphics, gamma

I ame using a class to increase and decrease the gamma of all my screens, then i start the program and increase or decrease the gamma it works fine, but after a while (20 seconds or so) it does not work anymore, ive located the problem and it seems to be the `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32();` i need to refresh this and then it works again. in the example code this is only done once during initialisation, but to make it work i have pasted the line inside the `SetBrightness()` method, so everytime it is refreshed. is it ok to do it like this or can i expect problems?

This is the code:

```
public static class Brightness
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private unsafe static extern bool SetDeviceGammaRamp(Int32 hdc, void* ramp);

    private static bool initialized = false;
    private static Int32 hdc;

    private static void InitializeClass()
    {
        if (initialized)
            return;

        //Get the hardware device context of the screen, we can do
        //this by getting the graphics object of null (IntPtr.Zero)
        //then getting the HDC and converting that to an Int32.
        hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32();

        initialized = true;
    }

    public static unsafe bool SetBrightness(short brightness)
    {
        InitializeClass();

        hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32();

        if (brightness > 255)
            brightness = 255;

        if (brightness < 0)
            brightness = 0;

        short* gArray = stackalloc short[3 * 256];
        short* idx = gArray;

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            {
                int arrayVal = i * (brightness + 128);

                if (arrayVal > 65535)
                    arrayVal = 65535;

                *idx = (short)arrayVal;
                idx++;
            }
        }

        //For some reason, this always returns false?
        bool retVal = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, gArray);

        //Memory allocated through stackalloc is automatically free'd
        //by the CLR.

        return retVal;

    }
}
```

This is how it is called:

```
short gammaValue = 128;

    void gammaUp_OnButtonDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gammaValue < 255)
        {
            gammaValue += 10;
            if (gammaValue > 255)
                gammaValue = 255;
            Brightness.SetBrightness(gammaValue);
        }
    }

    void gammaDown_OnButtonDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gammaValue > 0)
        {
            gammaValue -= 10;
            if (gammaValue < 0)
                gammaValue = 0;
            Brightness.SetBrightness(gammaValue);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how SetBrightness is called? i.e. how often, what else is changing hdc in the mean time...

Comment: @jamesj nothing else is changing hdc in the program except this code

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. With me, SetBrightness is called by a simple button I created. It works for 26 times. The 27th time, SetBrightness() fails to work. I'll create a bounty...

Comment: Unfortuantely, calling `hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32();` every time appears to create a memory leak. I'm not sure how to avoid this.

Comment: I've found out how to avoid the memory leak now at least. Create a Graphics object from `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)` (hdc can be obtained from that separately). Then at the end, use the Dispose() method to free the memory of the Graphics object.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very simple, classic memory management problem.

You need to keep a reference to

Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)

around, otherwise the garbage collector (incidentially GC too) will think you are not using your Graphics Context (GC).

Keeping a ref around means retaining a valid reference, somtimes called "live object".
In your class Brightness case it translates to (from memory, not compiled!)

```
private static bool initialized = false;
private static Graphics gc;

private static void InitializeClass()
{
    if (initialized)
        return;

    //Get the hardware device context of the screen, we can do
    //this by getting the graphics object of null (IntPtr.Zero)
    gc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);

    initialized = true;
}
```

and later you invoke SetRamp(gc.GetHdc().ToInt32(), ...);

The crucial point is that as long as Brightness is initialized, the Graphics object is needed, so the garbage collector will not free it.

You were only remembering it's numeric handle value, and when calling ReleaseDC() explicitly you were doing the runtime's job, crashing when the runtime does the same.

Comment: Can you give the actual code and placement to "keep the reference around"? I have an idea, but I want to make sure I get it right. Also what would I use instead of `IntPtr.Zero`, as there's no "SafeHandle.Zero" that I'd use in `Graphics.FromHwnd(SafeHandle.Zero).GetHdc()`. Also, shall I keep `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).ReleaseHdc();` just before the function return? Also did you mean ReleaseHdc() rather than ReleaseDC()?

Comment: I edited my answer to include that detail but this is really a classic, i.e. it's really about learning programming and your API. There is no substitute to that.

Comment: It wouldn't be just for me (with 5-10 minutes of experimentation, I probably could've figured it out). It's also to help other users in future so that they can implement the code immediately. In hindsight, declaring the Graphics variable outside seems obvious, though I think what tripped me up was perhaps that you didn't just say to keep a reference (or more 'global' scope) to the `Graphics` object (rather than to `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)`). Anyway, I wish I could have shared the bounty, but alas, only one was able to be awarded.

Comment: Sure. I admit that without the bounty I likely woudn't have bothered, so seemingly this was a good move (on overall).

Comment: If I could pay you 30 points of my 518 now, I would. Don't think Stackoverflow has any way of doing that though. With your skills though, I doubt it'll take long for you get into the hundreds or thousands! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the *error code* when your code fails you can use:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern uint GetLastError();

bool retVal = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, gArray);
if (retVal == false)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(GetLastError());
}
```

`error code is 87: ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

Clearly the *hdc* is the invalid parameter. This happens because in your:

```
hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc()
```

`Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)` is the graphic object from which you get the *hdc*. This object doesn't exist anymore thus the error.

Getting an hdc: `hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc()` every time the `SetBrightness` function is called solves the problem **but** *it crashes* (as you said in a comment) by calling `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).ReleaseHdc();`. This happens because `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero)` is not the same as the first one.

**SOLUTION**

There are many:

1.
Create the graphics object and get from it the dc handle every time *SetBrightness* is called, release the resources in the end:

```
public static unsafe bool SetBrightness(short brightness)
{
    Graphics gr;
    gr = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
    IntPtr hdc = gr.GetHdc(); //Use IntPtr instead of Int32, don't need private static Int32 hdc;

    ...
    ...

    //For some reason, this always returns false?
    bool retVal = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, gArray);

    //Memory allocated through stackalloc is automatically free'd
    //by the CLR.

    gr.ReleaseHdc();        
    gr.Dispose();

    return retVal;
}
```

2.
Create the graphics object and get from it the dc handle **once** in *InitializeClass()* function, release the resources in the end of the program:

```
private static IntPtr hdc;
private static Graphics gr;

private static void InitializeClass()
{
    if (initialized)
        return;

    gr = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero);
    hdc = gr.GetHdc();

    initialized = true;
}

public static unsafe bool SetBrightness(short brightness)
{
    InitializeClass();

    //hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc(); //You don't need it since we get the hdc once.

    ...
    ...

    //For some reason, this always returns false?
    bool retVal = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, gArray);

    //Memory allocated through stackalloc is automatically free'd
    //by the CLR.

    return retVal;
}
```

3.
Use `GetDC` api:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);

private static IntPtr hdc;

private static void InitializeClass()
{
    if (initialized)
        return;

    hdc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);

    initialized = true;
}

public static unsafe bool SetBrightness(short brightness)
{
    InitializeClass();

    //hdc = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc(); //You don't need it since we get the hdc once.

    ...
    ...

    //For some reason, this always returns false?
    bool retVal = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, gArray);

    //Memory allocated through stackalloc is automatically free'd
    //by the CLR.

    return retVal;
}
```

In the end of the program release hdc:

```
ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc);
```

Comment: Great. The first and second work perfectly. The third looks good, but GetDC() needs to pass a parameter, so won't compile (please edit). Can you put "Solution 1", "Solution 2", and "Solution 3" next to each solution to help make it clearer for others? Finally, which solution do you think has the least overhead in terms of CPU/GPU usage and stability?

Comment: @DanW There is no overhead for these methods. Which is best? If you call *SetBrightness*  from a button, the first one is more convenient(don't have to worry of releasing resources in the end). If *SetBrightness* is called many times a second, either the second or the third one. I whould prefer the umanaged solution, primarily because I program using C, so unmanaged code is more natural to me.

Comment: Thanks, the other answers were good, but yours takes the cake. Bounty awarded!

Comment: I would like to change the gamma of only the main display monitor (the one with the desktop).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem specifically with using `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32();` twice, although I would expect the value to be the same both times, unless something external to your program is affecting it.

I would be more concerned about the following section always returning false.

```
 //For some reason, this always returns false?
 bool retVal = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hdc, gArray);
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd372194%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifies

> Return Value
>
> If this function succeeds, the return value is TRUE.
>
> If this function fails, the return value is FALSE.

so I would say that something is not working correctly for that call to always return false.

Comment: The first time, when the program starts, it sets the gamma to 128, then it returns true, but for the other times it returns false, but the gamma is changed.

Comment: and the code 'Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).GetHdc().ToInt32();' is not called only twice, but every time the user clicks the up or down button, should this be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess this is because the device context handle returned by `GetHdc()` must be released after use, it's assumed that you'll do this as soon as possible; you should be able to release it immediately after calling `SetDeviceGammaRamp()` via [`ReleaseHdc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.releasehdc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Essentially any time you get a DC you should release it, and asap.

C# is providing only a thin veneer here over the Win32 GDI APIs, so the rules which apply are those of [`GetDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144871%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`ReleaseDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and you could pinvoke `GetDC()` with IntPtr.Zero to the same effect (and with the same issues).

The GDI is picky like this, you're only "borrowing" the handles and those you get are allocated are generally from a pool of a certain size, and once it runs out, you don't get any more DCs as you haven't released the previous ones. The same is true if one repeatedly allocates GDI brushes or pens to paint with; eventually you [run out](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/03/31/3322423.aspx). Further, retaining pooled handles generally doesn't work out well; I can't tell you exactly what the problem is with this inside the GDI, but I've hit similar issues before and barring driver problems I'd expect your approach to work if you get the DC, set the ramp, then release the DC immediately.

In passing, there are exceptions to these pairwise rules as noted in MSDN, for example for private DCs assigned to a window via Win32's [`CS_OWNDC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); those don't come from the pool, so you can keep them as long as you like.

Incidentally, unless you're forcing x86 builds I'd suggest using IntPtr instead of Int32 in `SetDeviceGammaRamp()`, since this is a pointer-sized integer rather than an always 32-bit value. And rather than `void*`, I'd define the `RAMP` structure or `MarshalAs` a fixed-length array. But I don't think either of these are causing your problem. Whilst you're at it, you could switch to calling `GetDC()` and `ReleaseDC()` via pinvoke and cut out a Graphics object you're not using. [PInvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net) has (at time of writing) a safer definition of [`SetDeviceGammaRamp()`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32.setdevicegammaramp) as well as [`GetDC()`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getdc) and [`ReleaseDC()`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.releasedc).

Comment: Thanks, I added `Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero).ReleaseHdc();` just before the end (`return retVal;`), but it crashes now. Can you perhaps supply code if it's much more involved? On another note, what do you think about using `Dispose()` and recreating the Graphics object each time (rather than just the first time)? That seems to solve the problem...